# How to collapse two array axis together of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

Basic idea: I have an array of images `images=np.array([10, 28, 28, 3])`. So 10 images 28x28 pixels with 3 colour channels. I want to stitch them together in one long line: `single_image.shape # [280, 28, 3]`. What would be the best numpy based function for that?

More generally: is there a function along the lines of `stitch(array, source_axis=0, target_axis=1)` that would transform an array `A.shape # [a0, a1, source_axis, a4, target_axis, a6]` into a shape `B.shape # [a0, a1, a4, target_axis*source_axis, a6]` by concatenating subarrays `A[:,:,i,:,:,:]` along `axis=target_axis`

Comment: What about a simple reshape, `images = images.reshape(-1, 28, 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it up with a single `moveaxis` + `reshape` combo -

```
def merge_axis(array, source_axis=0, target_axis=1):
    shp = a.shape
    L = shp[source_axis]*shp[target_axis] # merged axis len
    out_shp = np.insert(np.delete(shp,(source_axis,target_axis)),target_axis-1,L)
    return np.moveaxis(a,source_axis,target_axis-1).reshape(out_shp)
```

Alternatively, `out_shp` could be setup with array manipulations and might be easier to follow, like so -

```
shp = np.array(a.shape)
shp[target_axis] *= shp[source_axis]
out_shp = np.delete(shp,source_axis)
```

If `source` and `target` axes are adjacent ones, we can skip `moveaxis` and simply reshape and the additional benefit would be that the output would be a view into the input and hence virtually free on runtime. So, we will introduce a If-conditional to check and modify our implementations to something like these -

```
def merge_axis_v1(array, source_axis=0, target_axis=1):
    shp = a.shape
    L = shp[source_axis]*shp[target_axis] # merged_axis_len
    out_shp = np.insert(np.delete(shp,(source_axis,target_axis)),target_axis-1,L)
    if target_axis==source_axis+1:
        return a.reshape(out_shp)
    else:
        return np.moveaxis(a,source_axis,target_axis-1).reshape(out_shp)

def merge_axis_v2(array, source_axis=0, target_axis=1):
    shp = np.array(a.shape)
    shp[target_axis] *= shp[source_axis]
    out_shp = np.delete(shp,source_axis)
    if target_axis==source_axis+1:
        return a.reshape(out_shp)
    else:
        return np.moveaxis(a,source_axis,target_axis-1).reshape(out_shp)
```

Verify `views` -

```
In [156]: a = np.random.rand(10,10,10,10,10)

In [157]: np.shares_memory(merge_axis_v1(a, source_axis=0, target_axis=1),a)
Out[157]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```
def merge_axis(array, source_axis=0, target_axis=1):
    array = np.moveaxis(array, source_axis, 0)
    array = np.moveaxis(array, target_axis, 1)
    array = np.concatenate(array)
    array = np.moveaxis(array, 0, target_axis-1)
    return array
```